# how to load my own function automatically as R-package?

Tags: r

I built my own function and each time I need to run this function, I need to do that manulally. Is there any way that I can load it automatically as any R-package? Or can I build an R-package used only by me?

Comment: Yes, you can build an R package only used by you. If you build it and don't distribute it, you'll be the only user. How to build a package, can be found in the great book of Hadley Wickham, free to read online: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/

Comment: On a sidenote, please keep in mind that these kind of very broad questions fall outside the scope of SO. Look at the information, try it out, and if it doesn't work out as planned, come back with a specific question, including a code example. To answer your question now, we need to write a book.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I read a lot and search google for three days. All the idea I found are for package that we then need to distribute as I understand. So from your first comment, I understand that I can build my package and do not need to distribute it. Thanks again.

Comment: a faster way, if you don't need a package, save your function in its own R script and add `source(~/Your/Path/functions.R)` to your library calls in new scripts. Any functions in `functions.R` will get read in automatically.

Comment: Put your function inside the .Rprofile file. Every time when you fire R. It will get loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would recommend Nate Days solution, but you could also use Rs `save()` and `load()`functions to do this. It works on all R-objects and stores them in a binay .rda-file. You can store multiple objects as well.

Try:

`add <- function(x, y){return(x+y)}`

`save(add, file = 'add_function.rda')`

Whenever you need your function, do:

`load('add_function.rda')`

And `add()` would be available in the parent environment.

Answer (score -2):

There is a package called `pkgmaker` on CRAN that has a ton of tools and utilities for you to create your own packages. As an alternate option you might consider creating a `functions.R` script for you to store all of your personally created and often used functions. You can add the line `source('functions.R', local=TRUE)` to your programs, scripts or apps and your functions will be accessible to you. Thats how I handle the issue anyway. Cheers

Comment: `pkgmaker` is a toolset for low level utilities for package development. The main tools for package building are `Rtools` on windows (not a package), the package `devtools`, a number of base functions like `package.skeleton` which are hardly used since `devtools`, `roxygen2` and others are incorporated in RStudio.

And sourcing the function just places it in the global environment, where it can be overwritten. So that's not a solution either.